# Functional equivalent to if expressions with variable comparison

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I have some complex if statement which is not very well readable. it works similar to following example:

```
let a = 1
let b = 2
let test v = true
if a <> b then a - 1
else
   if (test a) then a + 1
   else a
```

Is there a better functional solution?  I thought of something like

```
match a with
| b -> ...
| _ -> ...
```

but this doesn't work, of course, since b becomes a within that statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it would look with a match

```
match a with
|foo when foo=b -> ..
|foo when test foo -> ...
|_ -> a
```

you need to use `when`

Comment: How easy. I already used when very often, but I got stuck with that simple problem. Now the code looks beautiful indeed.

Comment: TBH, I think this looks silly vs. an `if .. elif .. else` for this.

Comment: @ildjarn - I am inclined to agree

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing 'unfunctional' about `if..then..else` expressions; even Haskell has them ;)

While, as John Palmer's answer shows, you can write

```
match a with
| foo when foo <> b -> a - 1
| foo when test foo -> a + 1
| _ -> a
```

you can also write

```
if a <> b then a - 1
elif test a then a + 1
else a
```

Personally, in this case I'd prefer the `if..then..else` syntax, as it's slightly shorter and (IMO) more concise.